# Dereferencing an incremented pointer causing the pointer to change its value?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *x= 0;
    int y = 0;
    x = &y;
    *x = 1;
    printf("%i\n",x);//an address 
    printf("%i\n",*x);//1
    *(x+1)=10;
    printf("%i\n",x);//10 ---->unexpected
    printf("%i\n",x+1);//14 ---->more wierd
    printf("%i\n",*(x+1));//seg fault
    return 0;
}
```

In this case the last printf statement will output a seg fault. The value of x changes to 10 after *(x+1)=10. However the value of *(&y+1) is indeed changed to 10. The statement *(x+1)=10 should not affected x imo.

Comment: You should print an address with the `%p` specifier, and you must cast the pointer to `(void *)` when you do this. But, `*(x + 1) = 10` invokes undefined behavior. Nothing matters in your program after that.

Comment: What do you think `*(x+1) = 10;` should do? Why do you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used wrong control string for pointer (`%i`)

```
printf("%i\n",x);//10 ---->unexpected
```

You should use `%p` instead

```
printf("%p\n",(void*) x);
```

Also the access to pointer `(x + 1)` is causes undefined behavior, because the initial pointer `x` points to a single integer, and so dereferencing `(x + 1)` is out of bound and undefined.

Comment: it would be good to mention the out of bounds access `*(x+1)`

Comment: `x+1` is allowed (you can point one past the end of anything) but it may not be dereferenced

Comment: @M.M-- for completeness: you can point one past the end, but _not_ one before the beginning of an array object.

Comment: @DavidBowling what M.M said is well understood. What you said - can you cite the source?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll look into undefined behaviour. First time heard of it.

Comment: @artm-- ISO/IEC 9899:2011 6.5.6/8: "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise the behavior is undefined."